# Why do the vowels in "finite" change when "in" is added to it

Tags: pronunciation

I just noticed that the vowels in the word "finite" change when the prefix "in" is added to it. Why does this happen? Infinite could easily have been "infainait".

"in" + /ˈfʌɪnʌɪt/ = /ˈɪnfɪnɪt/ both the vowels have changed.

What causes the pronunciation to change?